# HttpResponse does not contain a definition for AddHeader for Dot Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, httpresponse, response-headers

When moving a project into .Net Core, `AddHeader` throws an error:

> Error CS1061  'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddHeader' and no extension method 'AddHeader' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)    .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Checkout](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/60)

Examples:

```
string combineValue = httpContext.Request.Headers["header1];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combineValue)) // ...
var values = httpContext.Request.Headers["header1"];
if (StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(values)) // ...
httpContext.Response.Headers["CustomHeader1"] = "singleValue";
httpContext.Response.Headers["CustomHeader2"] =  new[] { "firstValue", "secondValue" };
```

Comment: Your link is dead. check to make sure you entered it correctly.

Comment: Ah I see, good point, I am doing the combined values wrong, made it into single value only.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is to instead do the following (without using AddHeader) :

```
Response.Headers["key-goes-here"] = "value-goes-here";
```

Comment: thanks - "`IHeaderDictionary has a different indexer contract than IDictionary, where it will return StringValues.Empty for missing entries.`"

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just say:

```
Response.Headers.Add("key", "value");
```