# HttpResponse does not contain a definition for AddHeader, BufferedOutput and BinaryWrite

Tags: migration, httpresponse

I am migrating an application to .net core and got some errors here:

[image]

The error says 
    HttpResponse does not contain a definition for (each of these AddHeader, BufferedOutput and BinaryWrite) and no extension method accepting first argument ... could be found.  I've tried a couple of options from StackOverflow but none working for me for now.

How do you solve this in .net core?

Comment: For adding headers you can try: `context.Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment");`

Comment: Thank you @Stam.  That works for the AddHeaders

Comment: this post seems related to what you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178149/httpresponse-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addheader-for-dot-net-core